# Распознание девайса

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Как можно в коде прописать чтобы когда размер девайса было меньше 600px, то там показывал картинку, а если выше то видео?

```
<div class="player">

                                    <?php

                                      $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
                                      if($detect->isMobile()){
                                         $tr= '<img src="/templates/assets/images/button_ground_test.jpg" style="width:100%;">';
                                         $poster="[xfvalue_videopathimage]";
                                            if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/car.jpg"){
                                              echo $ec;
                                            }else if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/health.jpg"){
                                              echo $tr;
                                            }else if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/property.jpg"){
                                               echo $ec;
                                            }else if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/travel.jpg"){
                                                echo $tr;
                                            }

                                      }else{
                                        echo '<video class="player__video" width="506" height="506" muted preload="auto" playsinline poster="[xfvalue_videopathimage]"> <source src="[xfvalue_videopath]" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>';

                                      }
                                  ?>
```

или же чтобы когда заходишь через mobile то картинку, если через десктоп то видео

Comment: Код в вопросе не работает?

Comment: @u_mulder код работает, но предназначен для другого

Comment: Сделайте это через css (media query), а не php

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov у меня там 4 видео, каждое видео надо поменять на картинки, как в таком случае я должен использовать `media query`?

Comment: А в чем сложность? С сервера отдайте <img class="img" src=""/> и видео <video class="player__video"/>, а далее через css за счет mediaQuery скрывайте либо видео, либо картинку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

require_once('Mobile_Detect.php');
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// detect mobiles and tables
if ($detect->isMobile() && $detect->isTablet()) {
   echo "Буду показывать картинки";
}
else {
   echo "Буду показывать видео";
}
```

Используйте `mobile_detect` чтобы распознавать мобильные устройства